# Gantt chart in cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp, gantt-chart

I need Gantt chart in cakephp.I have tried Some Jquery Gantt charts .

But for my requirement i found 'dhtmlxGantt' is suitable.
But it works fine for only limited number of tasks.

Is there any solution for this.or any alternative charts ??Kindly suggest.

Comment: SO is not a site for recommendations

Comment: @Salines ok..how to improve the limit of tasks in dhtmlxGantt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try RadiantQ jQuery Gantt - www.radiantq.com. Support unlimited number of tasks through virtualization.